# What are the parameters for translating a rvt to a ifc and a dwg file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I just used the model-derivative api to create the ifc and a dwg file. I got it working, but now I want to see what parameters I can set in the post job command. But the documentation on https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/ isn't yet updated. Which parameters can I set for this job?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the request body structure table, there’s a property you can pass in called 'output.formats', where you can specify the format you want. There are examples requests there too.

I'll try to hunt down a table for DWG and IFC to set exact parameters to pass in.

When exporting to IFC, it does not matter whether or not there is a 3D view in the model. All the elements in the model would be exported to IFC as Revit does.

When exporting to DWG, it only exports the 'selected' 2D views of the model. You can choose which of the 2D views you need to exporting (to DWG) through Revit addon 'Publish Settings':

http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3

[image]

Figure 1 Publish Settings

If nothing is selected, all the sheet views (if any) will be exported by default.

Exporting IFC/DWG would use the pre-defined options saved in the RVT file, cf. the help links on DWG and IFC settings:

http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-E8443B4B-D55B-4630-BEE3-D2D8628CA17B

http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2017/ENU/?guid=GUID-14037C31-EBAD-41A8-9099-E6DD65BB626E

For DWG exporting, there is an option called 'Export views on sheets and links as external references':

[image]

Figure 2 DWG Export Settings

This can be set to request multiple DWGs or single DWG exporting. By default, the newly exposed API would exporting IFC/DWG using the active settings saved in RVT file. But the you can specify the name of the settings you want to use for exporting through Forge API.